# Как при клике на кнопку, перейти на ссылку + text, который был написан в <input type="text">, внутри html

Tags: html

Как при клике на кнопку, перейти на ссылку + text, который был написан в input type="text", внутри html. Мой код:

```
<form action="" method="post" onclick="">
<input type="text" name="search_bar_value" value="Имя" onfocus="this.value=''">
<input type="submit" name="search_bar_submit" value="Поиск">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Придётся не много изменить HTML код вашей формы

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="urlGo(this); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="search_bar_value" value="Имя" onfocus="this.value=''">
    <input type="submit" name="search_bar_submit" value="Поиск">
</form>
```

Здесь мы меняем метод `OnCLick` на `onSubmit`. В этот метод передаём название функции и отменяем срабатывание формы `return false`

JavaScript код функции

```
function urlGo(e) {
    let text = e.search_bar_value.value,  // Записываем значение поля search_bar_value
        url = '[THIS_IS_URL ]' // Ссылка, куда надо перенаправить пользователя 
    window.location.href = url + '/' + text; 

}
```